# Informix How to pass parameters to prepared statement in stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

Informix Dynamic Server 11.70

i tried to convert 4gl codes

```
let stmt =  'insert into tab1 values (?)'
prepare prep_stmt from stmt
let p_col1 = 'a'
execute prep_stmt using p_col1
```

to stored procedures

```
let stmt =  'insert into tab1 values (?)';
prepare prep_stmt from stmt;
let p_col1 = 'a';
execute immediate prep_stmt using p_col1;
```

Is the last line

```
execute immediate prep_stmt using p_col1;
```

possible in stored procedure?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention the database, it is Informix Dynamic Server 11.70

Comment: In general you should make clarifications by editing the question, not via comments...

Comment: Edited, thanks for the comment